# Instance of generic type not assignable to instance of mapped type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

Consider the following code: ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqAQwC5dRJyEBXAWwCMIAnAGigGc46IB5YABYsAYiggAbACblgzGhAC%20rAkQbkclCOQ6yUCNOy49%20Q5qInSoSYuI6LlCvHgD0zqACJi7qAB8PDdzxNKABpCBAsKABrcLgkWERUNABuFzcAJQhgGmYEDigAA1pGFgKrOGYPLxIESUKdZj00MqQK-0DggBVwPiQwkAAeEKgIAA9gCFr8-oA%20SPhkdABtEIBdJfdNd1W03DIoYqY2KDVOXX1HYIBJPOBiBABjaGx8IigVqD1Q8NXybsheH1wkMZngFKk8A9EDorJEhiNxpNJNNwjMABSjP49QH9EEASnINx09yeK1WWDmo1SrjetLp9IZjKZDIAeiNmMw2qYILt-tAAOR8nHAkIzfmffIIODAEgcDjoBDEBjiaDAOBQYL8ol3R4QMn8gB0u0IfKg-IWSX1EoO0tl8rQiuVqvVmu1JIghuNRFN-JwGp61HoR2SnG4fEEIjEUhkcggIYUvlw-qoZ0a%20hDRnDpnM0asNjs8fFKEltuIcoVSpVGpdPTNbt1nppdJ9fs0gZKzAzYZMkYsMfkhetdGL8v0GqE5XE4jgAHcmlAwJzIMxgGJ8khOXRkwL609%20eRiOwGHggA))

```js
type Config = {
    a: {type: number, someOtherField: true},
    b: {type: string, someOtherField: false},
}

// "a" | "b"
type Key = keyof Config;
// Returns `number` for "a" and `string` for "b"
type TypeOfKey<K extends Key> = Config[K]["type"]
// {a: number, b: string}
type Instance = {
    [K in Key]: TypeOfKey<K>
};

const f = <K extends Key>(x: TypeOfKey<K>): Instance[K] => x;
//                                                         ^ error here
// Type 'TypeOfKey<K>' is not assignable to type 'Instance[K]'.
//   Type 'Config[K]' is not assignable to type 'Instance'.
//     Type '{ type: number; someOtherField: true; } | { type: string; someOtherField: false; }' is not assignable to type 'Instance'.
//       Type '{ type: number; someOtherField: true; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Instance': a, b
```

I would expect it to work, given that `Instance` is defined by `Instance[K]` being `TypeOfKey<K>`, but the `["type"]` parts seems to throw Typescript off. In particular, in the second line of the error message, it seems like Typescript decided to unfold `TypeOfKey<K>`, and then assumed that for `Config[K]["type"]` to equal `Instance[K]` we need `Config[K]` to equal `Instance` (which is not true and makes no sense).

I'm guessing this is a known limitation, but I’m wondering if there is a way I can work around it, for instance by defining `TypeOfKey` or `Instance` slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

I would image error you're seeing is due to TypeScript's inability to directly correlate the generic `K` used in `TypeOfKey<K>` and the mapped properties in Instance. So yes, looks like an inference limitation problem.

However, you can get around this by directly using `Config[K]["type"]` instead of `TypeOfKey<K>` in your `Instance` type definition.

```
type Config = {
    a: {type: number, someOtherField: true},
    b: {type: string, someOtherField: false},
}

type Key = keyof Config;

type Instance = {
    [K in Key]: Config[K]["type"]
};

const f = <K extends Key>(x: Instance[K]): Instance[K] => x;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqAQwC5dRJyEBXAWwCMIAnAGigGc46IB5YABYsAYiggAbACblgzGhAC%20rAkQbkclCOQ6yUCNOy49%20Q5qInSoSYuI6LlCvHk1QA0hBBYoAaw9wksIioaADcTi4Akgg6xAgAxtDY%20ERQANquUHpuHgC65PDI6Ok5qQBEmqU5eApheHGIOlZeADwZEAAewBAIkhzZIAB8ABTt5FEx8RDFAJRj0cCxCcVYA1DtYUA)